# Spring boot custom starter thru Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

Any tutorial I found online, creates a custom spring boot starter thru Maven. Is there a way to create it using Gradle?

I tried to use gradle. It successfully creates a jar file for me. The condition is that I must have a main class. That's a problem I assume as any online tutorial I found that creates custom starter does not have a main method in them.

2nd issue is that the jar file that it produces, which works perfectly fine when run from cmd like this `java -jar jarname.jar`, has a directory structure where my custom configurations are not at the root. It has spring boot related stuff at the root. I am sure I need my classes to be at the root of the jar file.

Hence my question, how do I create a custom starter project thru gradle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you have applied Spring Boot’s Gradle plugin. If you are building a starter – a reusable library – you should not do that. Instead, you should only apply Gradle’s `java` or `java-library` plugins.

You may want to use Boot’s dependency management when building your starter. You can do that [by referencing Boot’s Gradle plugin but not applying it and importing its bom](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#managing-dependencies-using-in-isolation):

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE' apply false
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES
    }
}
```